Win32 API: reliably determining the last change time of a user password using USER_INFO_3::usri3_password_age?
AFAIK, the only way to get the time of the last password change on a user account is to call NetUserGetInfo() and then calculate the time based on PUSER_INFO_3::usri3_password_age. But, it seems the problem is that knowing exactly when the 0 second for usri3_password_age is unreliable.
I have an algorithm:
time_t seconds = time(NULL);
time_t time_of_change = seconds - pExtraUserInfo->usri3_password_age;

But unfortunately, time_of_change is sometimes 1 second off. That's because time(NULL) doesn't return what usri3_password_age considers to be the 0 second; it's a race condition.
Is time() just the wrong function to use for this calculation? Or is NetUserGetInfo() the wrong function?
I'm open to using different functions to get the point in time of the last password change, but I rather have it be LDAP-agnostic.

There will always be a race condition since you are querying two time points separately and time elapses between the queries. But to mitigate the issue, why not use something that has a higher precision than time(), such as GetSystemTime()/GetLocalTime(), or std::chrono in C++?

@RemyLebeau I'm trying std::chrono now, but since usri3_password_age only has second granularity, I'm expecting unacceptable results. I may have to resort to finding a way to tolerate minor differences, but that calls for magic numbers. I'd much rather the API just tell me the time of the last password update!

I'm not aware of another API that returns the actual time point of the change. But, can you please [edit] your question to explain what "the 0 second for usri3_password_age is unreliable" and "time(NULL) doesn't return what usri3_password_age considers to be the 0 second" actually mean? What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Can you provide an example?

@RemyLebeau I'm afraid I don't know a better way to word it. It means the point in time (what it thinks now is) that usri3_password_age considers 0 seconds ago.
An example would be sometimes I run the code and the date is calculated to be August 3, 2022 12:14:44 and other times it's August 3, 2022 12:14:45 and that's using std::chrono.

An age of 0 seconds would be the time of the last change, not the time of now. In any case, when are you calling time()? Your example implies you are calling time() after calling NetUserGetInfo(). You should call it before, if you are not already.

@RemyLebeau I'm calling std::chrono right after the call to NetUserGetInfo(). Why is calling before any better? By refactoring a loop I could call it right before, but I would assume that would be just as bad.
Now, if I really wanted to get the most out of it, I could do a std::chrono call right before NetUserGetInfo() and then another right after and hope that the midpoint between the 2 would be the closest to what NetUserGetInfo() expects. But that solution would be just as elegant as it is reliable

Other than querying LDAP or ActiveDirectory, I don't know any other API that can directly return the value you want. So, I think you have to live with the imprecision if you cant use those APIs. Does being 1 second off really make a difference?

@Opux Have you tried using GetSystemTime()/GetLocalTime()? Perhaps they could reduce the asynchronous time before and after NetUserGetInfo.

@RemyLebeau Yes, 1 second matters. Maybe I could change the code elsewhere that it would tolerate a 1-second drift, but then what happens when it drifts by 2? Or 3? That's why I bought up magic numbers.

@Torrecto-MSFT why would they be better than std::chrono?

@Opux Because std::chrono belongs to c++11. It may fit windows api precise. Also, please try GetSystemTimePreciseAsFileTime .

I've come to the conclusion that the best answer is: there is no answer. As commenters were getting at, PUSER_INFO_3::usri3_password_age is not supposed to be used to pin-point a point in time; it is just meant to give a vague idea of how old the current password is. I did manage to come up with an algorithm that has the potential to improve accuracy, but in my case, it wasn't enough. I had to apply a 10-second tolerance on drift.
    auto nowMillisBefore = getCurrentTimeInMillis();
    NetUserGetInfo(0, user_name, level, &pExtraUserInfo);
    auto nowMillisAfter = getCurrentTimeInMillis();
    double nowAverageMillis = (nowMillisAfter + nowMillisBefore)/2.; //taking average from time before and time after
    uint64_t nowSeconds = static_cast<uint64_t>(round(nowAverageMillis/1000.));

    //"current" in that it was calculated most recently
    uint64_t currentTimeOfChange = nowSeconds - pExtraUserInfo->usri3_password_age;
    bool bPasswordSetMoreRecently = currentTimeOfChange - olderTimeOfChange > nDriftTollerance;

The first part tries to find the point in time that NetUserGetInfo() considers to be now. The second part looks to see if there's a big enough change. If currentTimeOfChange is more than nDriftTollerance seconds than olderTimeOfChange then we know the password has been changed and we have a new date for that change. But who is to say how large nDriftTollerance should be? In my program, it was never more than 1 second, during dev testing, so I set nDriftTollerance to 10. But whose to say that's the right number?
As was also discovered, it looks like getting the password set time can't be done any better than what's afforded by NetUserGetInfo() for local users. I've heard there are other options for LDAP.
